# laravelAngular components 'ngInject'

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

have a short question, just took up a laravel-angular based project and spotted that all directives, components, etc. which will be used in views have this 'ngInject' in their constructors and I can't find what it does? How does it work? By the way template is written in Angularjs 1.5.8 es6. Example:

```
class AppHeaderController{
    constructor($sce){
        'ngInject';

        this.$sce = $sce;
    }

    $onInit(){
        //defer iframe loading
        let url = 'https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=jadjoubran&repo=laravel5-angular-material-starter&type=star&count=true&size=large';
        this.githubWidget = this.$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    }
}

export const AppHeaderComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/app-header/app-header.component.html',
    controller: AppHeaderController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {}
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Comment: Thanks man! really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer from comments, estus answered my question. To find out more about the 'ngInject' visit github.com/olov/ng-annotate.